# How to find the percentage of churner/non-churner in the excel data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

[image]

Want to find Churn and Non_Churn curstomer percentage from the following columns. How and on which baces we will decide that which column is churn and which is non_churn ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target_flag is your labels column.
Therefore

`dataframe["target_flag"].value_counts(normalize=True)` should do the work

0 will mean no churn and 1 will mean that churn.

Comment: Can you please help me to this another task.
2. Perform transformations. (At least two meaningful transformations are mandatory and explanation is required as to why these have been chosen)

Comment: @DaniyalBaig by transformations you mean any kind of data pre-processing? 
If so yes, I can help. 
For example, Total Revenue is a continuous value, therefore, if you draw its distribution, most probably it will have a Gaussian bell shape, however, it won't be normalized.

Therefore, we can import a a Scaler for the data, and transform this column to values between 0 and 1 for example that have the same scale.

Comment: @DaniyalBaig please read here, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html , 
You will understand more. Also if you have a good statistics background you will grasp it in a second.